# Borel Algebra: Nonexample?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Are there any sigma-algebras not induced by some topology?
*(I'm thinking of something over finite space but not sure wether it must be infinite.)*

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/a/87888 for an answer

Comment: Ok so it's not as easy to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ok so let me check off my thread.*

Due to cardinality-reasons there are sigma-algebras that are not Borel-algebras.

*(See the link provided in the comments.)*